# Does Google Cloud Vision API detect formatting in OCRed text like bold, italics, font name (helvetica or times new roman), etc?

Tags: ocr, tesseract, google-cloud-vision, abbyy, abbyy-cloud-ocr

The quick **brown** fox jumps *over* the lazy dog

In such a case like this, assuming there are different font families too, can cloud VIsion API detect this. Or any other OCR API detect this cleanly. Tesseract has capabilities but its so inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

> Does google cloud vision API detect formatting in OCRed text like
> bold, italics, font name (helvetica or times new roman), etc?

Unfortunately, no.

In my project, I use [ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK](https://www.ocrsdk.com/) for this purpose. If you want to try, you can [start free trial](https://cloud.ocrsdk.com/Account/Register/?skipIfLoggedIn=true) which includes 500 free requests (pages). After you create your trial account, you will receive an email from ABBYY which will contain your Application ID and Application password. Use these 2 values to create your authentication header according to [Authentication](https://www.ocrsdk.com/documentation/api-reference/authentication/).

See the following example:

1. Perform [processImage](https://www.ocrsdk.com/documentation/api-reference/process-image-method-v2/) request. Pass your image in the request body.

Request:

```
POST / https://cloud.ocrsdk.com/v2/processImage?exportFormat=xml&profile=documentConversion&xml:writeFormatting=true
Authorization: <your token>
```

Response:

```
{
    "taskId": "a226a0b6-6705-4d6f-9f4c-517fa9b4e28e",
    "registrationTime": "2020-07-26T09:42:39Z",
    "statusChangeTime": "2020-07-26T09:42:39Z",
    "status": "Queued",
    "filesCount": 1,
    "requestStatusDelay": 10000
}
```

2. Perform [getTaskStatus](https://www.ocrsdk.com/documentation/api-reference/get-task-status-method-v2/) request in order to check if your task is completed. Use taskId from the response of the previous step.

Request:

```
GET / https://cloud.ocrsdk.com/v2/getTaskStatus?taskId=a226a0b6-6705-4d6f-9f4c-517fa9b4e28e
Authorization: <your token>
```

Response:

```
{
    "taskId": "a226a0b6-6705-4d6f-9f4c-517fa9b4e28e",
    "registrationTime": "2020-07-26T09:42:39Z",
    "statusChangeTime": "2020-07-26T09:42:40Z",
    "status": "Completed",
    "filesCount": 1,
    "requestStatusDelay": 0,
    "resultUrls": [
        "https://ocrsdk.blob.core.windows.net/files/a226a0b6-6705-4d6f-9f4c-517fa9b4e28e.result?sv=2012-02-12&se=2020-07-26T19%3A00%3A00Z&sr=b&si=downloadResults&sig=4k9FcRoBfhodq%2BMj%2Ffj%2BGLBfwK2BsO7sj15JQOLcArk%3D"
    ]
}
```

3. Download the result (see resultUrls from the response of the previous step).

I used the following picture
[image]
and received the following result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

ABBYY Cloud OCR will be quite accurate, but at the end, everything depends on your fonts and scanning quality.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud's Enterprise Document OCR product has [add-ons for font style](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/process-documents-ocr#font-style_detection) detection