# Does Google Vision detect text retain formatting information?

Tags: json, ocr

I am using Google Vision API to extract data from old newspapers. I want to extract performance data from the last page of each newspaper. When I use Google Drive's OCR, the formatting information is retained (i.e. bold and italics), but when I look at the json that Google Vision creates, I don't see any formatting information. Is there an option in the async_detect_document(gcs_source_uri, gcs_destination_uri) function to retain formatting?

Below is an example of the pdf and the Google Drive rendering. As you will see from the examples, the formatting information is a shortcut for finding the theatrical venue, work, author and actor of each performance.

[Original PDF of Newspaper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgjyi.png)

[Google Drive OCR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur18Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer below. A friend suggested I could try to use Google Drive's API too.

[Does Google Cloud Vision API detect formatting in OCRed text like bold, italics, font name (helvetica or times new roman), etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62947592/does-google-cloud-vision-api-detect-formatting-in-ocred-text-like-bold-italics)