# Extracting Only Bold Text from an image using any OCR

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I want to extract and print only the **bold** text from an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5eun.jpg) using any OCR tesseract, easyOCR etc.
Thanks in advance

```
import easyocr
import cv2

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

IMAGE_PATH = 'captcha4.JPG'

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
result = reader.readtext(IMAGE_PATH)
print(result)
```

Below is the output i am getting

```
[([[3, 21], [19, 21], [19, 45], [3, 45]], 'B', 0.9924401414986086), ([[32, 18], [72, 18], [72, 44], [32, 44]], 'IdE', 0.08095396599328475), ([[92, 2], [218, 2], [218, 50], [92, 50]], 'EP', 0.612884916567028)]
```

Comment: Did this one not help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/5163329/7933454

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'm not familiar with openocr. However I think to output the text you will already need a trained architecture (or the trained parameters). What you are getting as output are the bounding boxes of your image.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.